# problemas al correr un proyecto de spring boot en un server weblogic 12c

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic

He estado intentando levantar un proyecto local en un servidor local de weblogic 12c pero no tengo resultados. Si ejecuto el proyecto con Spring boot App funciona y muestra la vista. Pero cuando trato de usar weblogic para que funciona.

Les muestro lo que tengo en mi proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Archivo weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.8/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.2.1</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>greeting</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor> 
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Cuando ejecuto el proyecto con weblogic me aparece esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en consola ni siquiera me muestra algun error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anteriormente tenia en la consola tenia un detalle que me aparecía esto:
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default.

solo agregue el properties esto y en el pom.xml habia agregado otras cosas que se muestran al final de archivo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahorita no entiendo porque no funciona. He trabajando con jsf y conweblogic y ahi tenia que configurar el archivo jsf donde agregaba los servelet y el web.xml para que supiera como mapear las cosas, pero aqui no se como se hace todo esto.

Ojala puedan orientarme, llevo varios dias inventigando y lo logo que funcione un proyecto con weblogic

Comment: Segun veo en el log no estas inicializando todo el contexto de spring, puedes confirma que además de la configuración que has mostrado, creaste la clase para inicializar el servlet de SpringBoot que es quien iniciara todo el aplicativo cuando lo despliegas en un servidor de aplicaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Aparte de configurar la aplicación de `jar a war` debes de crear un clase que inicialice el servlet que ejecutara todo el contexto de spring, que es necesario cuando realizas el despliegue en un servidor de aplicaciones, según la documentación la clase seria de la siguiente forma:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(ApplicationInitializer.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication sa = new SpringApplication(ApplicationInitializer.class);
        sa.run(args);
    }

    @RestController
    public static class WarInitializerController {

        @GetMapping("/")
        public String handler() {
           return "Proyecto Iniciado!";
        }
    }
}
```